# Entity Framework migration doesn't drop index constraint

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I have EF.Core 2-based model with SQL Server as back end. One of the fields (`Delete_Flag`) used to be `int` and I want to change it to `bool`. Also, there is an index defined on this field. So, when I add migration, I get the following SQL generated and executed (`CrForce` is the name of the table):

```
DECLARE @var0 sysname;
SELECT @var0 = [d].[name]
   FROM [sys].[default_constraints] [d]
   INNER JOIN [sys].[columns] [c] ON [d].[parent_column_id] = [c].[column_id] AND [d].[parent_object_id] = [c].[object_id]
   WHERE ([d].[parent_object_id] = OBJECT_ID(N'[CrForce]') AND [c].[name] = N'Delete_Flag');
IF @var0 IS NOT NULL EXEC(N'ALTER TABLE [CrForce] DROP CONSTRAINT [' + @var0 + '];');
ALTER TABLE [Crime_Force] ALTER COLUMN [Delete_Flag] bit NOT NULL;
```

The problem is that `SELECT` statement doesn't return and data, and `DROP CONSTRAINT` is not run. However, there **is** an index; so when `ALTER TABLE` is run, I get the following error:

```
The index 'IX_CrForce_Delete_Flag' is dependent on column 'Delete_Flag'.
ALTER TABLE ALTER COLUMN Delete_Flag failed because one or more objects access this column.
```

The error makes sense, but why the constraint isn't dropped in the first place?

Incidentally, if I *explicitly* remove the index from my `DbContext`-derived class, it works fine. But I have a number of columns like that, and I would prefer not to remove (and then add) the indexes

Comment: Did you add the index with an EF migration?

Comment: Yes, I did. It's in the DBContext class as `entity.HasIndex(e => e.DeleteFlag);`

Comment: I don't think EF removes indexes. It only adds them. If you want to remove the index, just drop it in the database directly.

Comment: @ChrisPratt - EF *does* remove index. As I mentioned, when I removed `hasIndex()` from `DbContext`, EF dropped the index and everything worked fine. What didn't work is the attempt to automatically drop index through the SQL that got generated. In the end, since I can't think of any other way - I removed indexes explicitly; and then created a migration that established them back. I wish there was a better way, but I couldn't wait